# Mocked method is still being called with Scala, ScalaTest, and Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am trying to mock a method that inserts data into the database. However when I try mocking the method, it is still being called. I have no idea why. Here is my test:

```
  //val mockDAO = mock[DAO]
  val mockDAO = spy(new DAO)
  val transObj = TransactionDataObj(-1, 1, 1, 9, 9, DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(), 99, 9969, 3)
  val additionalObj = AdditionalTransData(Some(90), Some(91), Some(92), Some(93), Some(94: Long))
  //stub(mockDAO.addTransaction(transObj, additionalObj)).toReturn(transObj)
  doReturn(transObj).when(mockDAO).addTransaction(transObj, additionalObj)
  //when(mockDAO.addTransaction(transObj, additionalObj)).thenReturn(transObj)

  "ControllerActor" must {
    "create nameless actor when a duplicate arises for the AdderActor" in {
      val controller = system.actorOf(Props[Controller])
      val msg = Add(transObj, additionalObj)
      controller.tell(msg, testActor)
      expectMsg(true)
   }
```

As you can see I have tried all sorts of combination. According to this [website](http://stevenschwenke.de/spyingWithMockito)
doReturn will not call the original method, however it does. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is DAO instantiated in the code which you want to test?

Comment: You can check if this method is final by any chance. In that case it can't be mocked with Mockito.